# System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary while sending Push Notifiaction from PUSHSHARP

Tags: c#, json, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

**Getting Exception while send notification from server to gcm.** 
as APNS notification are working fine.

```
apps["com.app.myAPP"].Gcm.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification
        {

            RegistrationIds = new List<string> {
         deviceId

        },
            Data = JObject.Parse(msg),


        });
```

Where

```
msg = "{ \"Somekey\" : \"somevalue\" }";
```

will highly  thankful to you if someone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: "com.app.myAPP" is probably not it your apps collection

Comment: Yes you are right ..bundles of  thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue Found**

I was not using correct app name apps["com.app.myApp"] .

Thanks